# How to change text to invisible, but still show underline?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, visibility, getelementsbytagname

I made a studying tool using Javascript and PHP. There's a toggle that shows/hides keywords in a paragraph, so the user can mentally "fill in the blanks".

How I've done this so far is that the all the keywords are underlined, and I use a DOM selector to select all innerHTML in u tags.

```
<p>
  Example sentence, <u>this</u> is a <u>keyword</u>.
</p>
<button onClick='hideKeywords()'>Hide Keywords</button>

<script>
  function hideKeywords() {
    var x = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('u'));
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works as intended - the "keywords" are blanked out and the flow of the document is unaffected, since the keywords still take up the same space that they would normally take.

One downside is that in paragraphs with particularly long "keywords", the paragraph's line structure is disrupted and it looks like text is just floating randomly in space. This would be fixable if I could somehow change visibility such that the words in the keywords are hidden and the text-decoration (underline) still shows. This retains the line structure.

I thought about using Javascript to replace every character in the keyword with underscores, but two more problems pop up. One thing is that even if the number of characters stay the same, the width might change.. For example, "apple" is not the same physical length as "______". This is not ideal as the document flow would change. A second problem is that I can't think of any way to get the keywords back after converting them into underscores.

One workaround is instead of changing the visibility to "hidden", I could change the background-color to the same color as the text. This blocks out the text, but the line structure and document flow are both preserved. However, I do hope to find a way to implement my original idea, so any suggestion is appreciated!

Update: I would prefer not to add any additional divs to the keywords. The user can add new entries using a rich text editor, so declaring a keyword is as easy as underlining it in the text editor.

Comment: use a solid line bottom border

Comment: @JaromandaX `bottom-border`'s width can't be changed.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks but that doesn't work. When I change the visibility to "hidden", the bottom border is hidden too.

Comment: What is your font size?

Comment: @Jodast The font size is 20px. I'm curious as to how that might change things?

Comment: @Panpaper just something for the code I'm writing in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with css adding a pseudo-element and instead of using visibility hidden, using color: transparent, like this:

```
u{
  position:relative;
}
u::after{
  content: ' ';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:1px;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

And in the script

```
<script>
  function hideKeywords() {
    var x = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('u'));
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.color = "transparent";
    }
  }
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROoMaM

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you so much! I just need to remove the original underline in the u tag to avoid getting an extra thick line.

Comment: I found a small problem with your solution. It seems like when the underlined text (keywords) breaks into a new line, the added underline would disappear. It's a little problematic as my website is optimized for mobile and the text breaks change all the time. Do you know of any solutions? Thanks very much!

Comment: @Panpaper can you give me a more detailed example? im trying with the keywords in all places and cant find it.

Comment: So take this following sentence as an example.

This sentence has an underlined section <u>that is really long
and breaks into a new line</u>. 

In this scenario, the extra underlining that we added with "u::after" does not appear.

Comment: @Panpaper You can put "every single long keyword" in a <u></u> and pseudoelements just start on each one of theese, like this: <u>that </u> <u>is </u> <u>really </u> <u>longs </u> <u>and </u> <u>breaks </u>  <u>into </u> <u>a </u> <u>new </u> <u>line</u>

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement this using your second method. Set the text colour to the same as the background then add a bottom border to the element. Preserves the spacing and allows you to quickly check if you are right by just highlighting the line. Also, if you give the keyword wrapper element a class you can easily just toggle the color of the hidden text, and retain the underlines so you can see what has changed.

```css
div {
  color: black;
}
span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
This <span>is hidden</span> with an underline
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to find some way to get the div positioned under the hidden text, but you can use the following code to create a div with the width of the text.  I might come back later after answering and find a way to position the div.

In your HTML, let's say you have a phrase, `foo bar`, that you want hidden.  You will assign an id to it with the code: `<p id="foo">foo bar</p>`

Here is the CSS:

```
#foo {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then in your Javascript, you can use the following code:

```
var fontSize = 20;                          //this defines a font size   
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.style.fontSize = fontSize;              //this sets the style as the font size
var width = (foo.clientWidth) + "px"

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = width;
div.style.height = 2px;
div.style.background = "red";      //makes the underline visible

document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
```

From here, you could probably just reposition the div how you want so it appears under the text.  This way, the div is the exact length of the text.

An alternative solution would be to use a monospace font and then manually calculuate the width.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately this adds some dependence on font size which might not be good for mobile views. The website is designed to be responsive and the font-size could change dynamically when viewed on mobile.